# When does body.rendered get called with meteor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

In the new meteor.js `BLAZE` integration, when does the `rendered`callback get executed. I want to initialize site wide JQuery plugins but only when the `<body>` component object is fully rendered. The documentation says, we can define helpers and event maps on the `UI.body`  just like on any `Template.myTemplate` object. I put my code below in a `Meteor.startup()` and before anything else but it never output's anything to the console:

```
UI.body.rendered = function(){
    console.log('clal');
}
```

Comment: [This part of documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#ui_body) states that you can define **helpers** and **event maps** for `UI.body`. `rendered` callback is neither.

Comment: @HubertOG Do you know what is the new suggested way since there isn't a `body` tag anymore. What template can we attach to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UI.body` is an **instantiated** Blaze component, and hence you can't attach a rendered callback to it. It's defined in a special way.

However, `Meteor.startup()` runs after the `<body>` tag is created, and this should be the only time that the tag is rendered. So it should be safe just to do any rendered operation in the startup function.

Also, note that `<body>` is special as you can have several `<body>` tags in your Meteor templates and they will be all concatenated into the single reified body in your page.